# Can a file ( such as PNG image ) wear out if transferred via SSH ( scp ) 1000s of times back and forth?

Tags: files

The question is about anything really. But in my case it is PNG images.

Can they wear out if transferred in-between 
servers over and over again?

I send them to another server and then 
retrieve them back after my server has gone through os-reload and so on.

Will they lose quality if moved too many
times between servers?

Answer (score 3):

Data transferred is [protected by multiple checksums.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction#Internet). But because of the checksums in use, it's possible for [multi-bit errors to pass](http://noahdavids.org/self_published/CRC_and_checksum.html) the ethernet, IP and TCP checksums. Given enough time, every possible situation turns up, so eventually, your PNG will luck out and get changed bits. So my conclusion is that your PNGs can "wear out". It also looks to me like there's a really, really low probability of this happening. I'm don't have any idea of how to estimate this sort of probability. My intuition says to not worry about it. Other occurances are vastly more likely.

Answer (score 0):

No in computer all data is digital so there is no loss for data in general but some times when lossy compression or conversation is used so data is trimmed. Transferring data (if it is completed successfully) do not lose anything.

Comment: In principle, there's the possibility of bit errors. For example, a bit can be flipped by a cosmic ray particle hitting a memory cell that currently holds the data. That's why servers usually use ECC memory. You could certainly see an accumulation of bit errors over time as "wearing out", since in the (extremely) long term, the data will turn into white noise (note that error correction will significantly increase that time, but will not completely eliminate bit errors, since there's a tiny, but nonzero chance that several bit errors occur between checks so that the checksum is right).

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to complete the answers already given: @Bruce_Ediger is right about the multiple checksums.

You've also asked :

> Will they lose quality if moved too many times between servers?

The simple answer is no. There is no lossy compression occurring when copying files with scp. There may however be stream compression, if enabled. That stream compression has no impact on the quality of the file, be it a png file or anything else.

Also, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439662/data-distortion-after-using-scp-for-transfer/8439741#8439741) to a very similar question may be helpful: